# How to Stream from VLC using Multicast?

Tags: multicast, gns3, streaming, pim

I have the following topology:
[image]

With the following router configurations:

R1:

```
hostname R1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
ip multicast-routing
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat outside
 duplex full
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip pim sparse-dense-mode
 duplex full
!
interface FastEthernet2/0
 ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip pim sparse-dense-mode
 duplex full
!
router ospf 1
 network 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 network 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 network 192.168.3.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 network 192.168.4.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 network 192.168.5.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
!
ip nat inside source list 1 interface FastEthernet0/0 overload
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
access-list 1 permit any
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
end
```

R2:

```
hostname R2
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip name-server 8.8.8.8
ip multicast-routing
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0
 ip pim sparse-dense-mode
 duplex full
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 ip address 192.168.3.1 255.255.255.0
 ip pim sparse-dense-mode
 duplex full
!
interface FastEthernet2/0
 ip address 192.168.5.1 255.255.255.0
 ip pim sparse-dense-mode
 duplex full
!
router ospf 1
 network 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 network 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 network 192.168.3.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 network 192.168.4.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 network 192.168.5.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
end
```

R3:

```
hostname R3
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
!
no aaa new-model
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip name-server 8.8.8.8
ip multicast-routing
ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.2.2 255.255.255.0
 ip pim sparse-dense-mode
 duplex full
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 ip address 192.168.4.1 255.255.255.0
 ip pim sparse-dense-mode
 duplex full
!
interface FastEthernet2/0
 ip address 192.168.5.2 255.255.255.0
 ip pim sparse-dense-mode
 duplex full
!
router ospf 1
 network 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 network 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 network 192.168.3.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 network 192.168.4.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
 network 192.168.5.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.2.1
!
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
end
```

What I tried to do is configure Multicast PIM Dense mode, so I can stream a video from the server to the client using VLC. In VLC I select the Stream option, added the video, selected stream, then in next destination I chose RTP/MPEG TS and in the address I wrote 239.255.0.1 with port 5004, I disabled transcoding and started the stream, but the video for some reason doesn't play in the server. In the client I connect to the network using rtp://239.255.0.1:5004. The stream is not working and I can't figure out why. I'm simulating the network in GNS3.

Comment: Did you try to increase the TTL from 1 to 10 in VLC.  VLC may be sending packets with TTL = 1 and thats why they are dropped at first hop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default , in VLC multicast packets are sent with TTL = 1. As a result , the multicast stream packets are dropped at the first hop router.

To make multicast work in your environment , you have to increase the TTL from 1 to 10 in VLC media player (say for example) to avoid multicast stream packets from being dropped at first hop router.